# Problems displaying image in C++ with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Code here: https://gist.github.com/protectivetoast83/25301772cbc6f13e6e07

images of problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

The program should be displaying a single gray rectangle at coordinates 32, 32 on the window however it was also displaying a second one at coordinates 0,0.

I added a *cout* statement on line 60 of gameWorld.cpp and the program started working correctly. The program works correctly only so long as I have that *cout* statement there.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) goes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 57 of gameWorld.cpp looks suspicious:

```
if(objSet[i].checkActive());
```

That semicolon ends the if statement ("if object i is active, do nothing"), and the subsequent four lines are a bare inner block that always gets executed.  (This explains why, in your second screenshot, you're looping over all objects from `i=0` to `99` as shown by the text box in the lower-right corner.  It doesn't tell me why adding line 60 changes your code's behaviour, though.)

Comment: Nice! This appears to fix it. Thanks! But yeah, it still doesn't make sense why this problem was occurring in the first place.

Comment: @cafemolecular Ehm, yes it does? Or do you mean that adding line 60 fixing the problem doens't make sense? It could be due to the compiler optimizing the code differently when you have the std::cout-statement. Have you tried building with different settings, `-g`, `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`, etc? Have you tried debugging it to see what happens?

Comment: @gurka Compiler optimization sounds like the right answer here, since `cout` would force the loop body to run for every object in `objSet`.